# PHP/AJAX - Update 2 Form Field Values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML form with 3 fields. The first one lets users select a Template from a select menu, the 2nd one is for an Email Subject and the 3rd is for the Email Message Body. At the moment I have setup a script that fires when a user changes the Template select menu to insert a message body.

I would like to extend this so that the Email Subject is also updated at the same time, but I'm not sure of the syntax to set 2 form values at the same time.

Here's the relevant part of my form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname" class="control-label col-sm-3">Template</label>
        <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
            <select class="form-control" name="templateRef" id="templateRef" onchange="getTemplate(this.value)">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1000">Template 1</option>
                <option value="2000">Template 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postcode" class="control-label col-sm-3 left-label">Subject</label>
        <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailSubject" id="emailSubject" placeholder="Subject">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postcode" class="control-label col-sm-3 left-label">Message</label>
        <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" name="emailBody" placeholder="Body" id="messageBody"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my script which calls a PHP page which currently returns the appropriate messageBody for the selected Template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTemplate(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("messageBody").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("messageBody").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        var status = xmlhttp.status == 200 ? 'success' : 'error'
        var group = document.getElementById("messageBody")
        group.classList.add(status)
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "getEmailTemplate.php?tempalteID=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to return the messageBody and the emailSubject and have both updated at the same time? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, just add the element to the XML template and add a line to change it right before you do the same thing for the messageBody. Also recommend using json with jquery, little cleaner and easier to work with when doing external requests like this, you can eliminate 80% of your code by using $.getJSON

Comment: For simple, At your php response append the subject data with your messageBody like **return $messageBody."~".$emailSubject**, here the symbol ~ is delimiter for example. and split these data at javascript use split function **response.split("~")**. But using json data is an effective way.